# ElasticSearch client connection impossible

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having problems with ElasticSearch Client.

I have designed a Java application (to finish my developer studies) that manage different databases MySQL, mongoDb and ElasticSearch. 
I was able to read, create and update data from a db to another.
All was designed and coded with local databases and everything works very well.
All the tests have been validated so we decide to make it work on distant servers on the real databases.

And then the problems begin to happened, and especially the one i'm stuck with since two long days and i'm getting really desperate.

- With TransportClient it worked on local, but on real server it bring a NoNodeAvailableException saying that none of the configured nodes are available. Have try a lot of things to make it work but it doesn't.
- So i decide to try connect and request with REST. Here is my code, and the error i got is not very detailed : it's a ConnectException.

Code :

```
    // Get the connection client from ES database
    public static RestHighLevelClient getConnection()
    {
        // Singleton
        if(client == null)
        {
            try             
            {       
                // Set Credz
                final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("Login", "pwd"));             

                // Builder
                RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("ServerIP", 9200, "http")).setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpClientBuilder) 
                    {   
                        System.out.println("Setting taken !");
                        return httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                    }
                });                 

                // Create client
                client = new RestHighLevelClient (builder);

                ClusterHealthRequest healthReq = new ClusterHealthRequest("looppy-cluster");
                ClusterHealthResponse response = client.cluster().health(healthReq, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    int numberOfNodes = response.getNumberOfNodes(); 
            System.out.println("Nodes Nb : " + numberOfNodes);

            } 
            catch(Exception ex)
            {   
System.out.println("Client connection problem");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       

        return client;
    }
```

And here is the exception i got :

```
    java.net.ConnectException
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$SyncResponseListener.get(RestClient.java:943)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:227)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1256)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1231)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.ClusterClient.health(ClusterClient.java:146)
    at utils.ElasticSearchMng.getConnection(ElasticSearchMng.java:86)
    at utils.ElasticSearchMng.getLoopiesFromES(ElasticSearchMng.java:133)
    at program.Program$1.run(Program.java:96)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.RouteSpecificPool.timeout(RouteSpecificPool.java:168)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestTimeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.timeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:822)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.timeout(SessionRequestImpl.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processTimeouts(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:210)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:348)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:192)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm getting despered and ireally don't understand what's happening, would appreciate a lot if someone can help !

thx a lot guyz

Comment: Did you change the network.host params (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#common-network-settings) in your elasticsearch.yml file from _local_ to an ip? If so elasticsearch entered "production mode" and add some bootstrap check before starting. Are you sure your elastic cluster is running fine ? Could you post your network configuration ?

Comment: Thanks for your help Pierre

Answer (score 0):

The problem is finally resolved, the port was not the good one, the peoples who work with the servers have tell me the port because they changed it and it directly worked ;)